# EF6 Code first navigation property with custom association

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I would like to use EF Code first to handle a custom association (or navigation property) that is not based on a key but on one of the property values of an entity.

My classes are these

```
public class MyConfig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InstanceNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}

public class MyAsset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<MyConfig> MyConfigs { get; set; }

    public int InstanceValue { get; set; }
}
```

So I would like a collection of MyConfig entities on any of the MyAsset entities. When the MyAsset entity is loaded from the database, I would like it to contain a list of MyConfig-entities whose value in its "InstanceNumber" matches the InstanceValue of the MyAsset entity.

Can I do this with EF6 codefirst? I have read up on overriding the built-in conventions of EF, but I have only been able to find solutions that work with specific primary keys.

And does the above make sense at all?

Comment: You can't have foreign keys to properties that EF doesn't know as primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can see that why you would like to do this but currently your only option is to use the Include extension method and get all MyConfig instances then you need to filter the list of MyConfig instances in MyAsset instance you queried like this:

```
public class MyAssetRepository : IMyAssetRepository
{
    public MyAsset Get(int assetId)
    {
        using (var context = new AssetContext())
        {
            var selectedAsset = context.MyAssets.Include(a => a.MyConfigs).Single(a => a.Id == assetId);
            selectedAsset.MyConfigs = selectedAsset.MyConfigs
                .Where(c => c.InstanceNumber == selectedAsset.InstanceValue)
                .ToList();

            return selectedAsset;
        }
    }
}
```

As in this example getting a MyAsset instance is encapsulated in a repository so the logic of getting a MyAsset instance with its MyConfig entities is encapsulated and hidden from the code outside of the repository.

Of course the overhead of getting all MyConfig entities will be present which could be resolved by using an Include extension method that accepts a filter argument, however it does not exist currently.

Comment: Hey, yes the performance penalty is quite obvious here, and since has a requirement for high performance, I am a bit reluctant to use it.

However, we looked at it earlier today and decided to add a mapping-table between the two tables mentioned above, and that works like a charm. We'll revisit this when the feature is added to #EF :-). Tank you!